# passing variable value from controller to view in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am developing an application where i popup a window and when it gets popup the next time i will try to open it should not be opened. Next time it should open When i will close the popup then it should open.

Now for that i am using count variable and whenever it will be 1 the popup opens and whenever it is greater than or equal to 2 it shows alert. But now when i close the popup it is not resetting the value of count to 0 in view. 
In JSfiddle i tried using var self = this; it works fine but when i tried it on my code it says Uncaught Exception Typeerror cannot find property 'count' defined at line self.count = 0; 
How to achieve this? or any alternate solution for this?

```
<a ui-sref-active="active" ng-click="count=count+1; connectMachine(machine, count)" ng-init="count=0" ><span><i class="fa fa-desktop fa-5x"></i></span></a>

$scope.connectMachine = function(machine, count) {
    var promise = restAPIService.connectMachineService(
            $scope.thisStudentThisBatch.guacProfileId,
            machine.connectionId, $stateParams.batchID).get();
    promise.$promise.then(function(response) {
        var json = JSON.parse(response.data);
        console.log(json.id);
        var dnsUrl = $location.absUrl().split('/');
        dnsUrl = dnsUrl[0] + '//' + dnsUrl[2];
        var apiUrl = dnsUrl + $rootScope.apiUrl + "guacamole/disconnect/"
                + json.id;
        var conn_params = $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization
                + "++" + apiUrl;
        $scope.machineURL = response.headers.url + "&conn_params="
                + conn_params;
        var params = "height=" + screen.availHeight + ",width="
                + screen.availWidth;

        var NewWin;
        var self = this;
        if ($scope.count == 1) {
            NewWin = window.open($scope.machineURL);
        } else if ($scope.count >= 2) {
            alert("Back Off Back Off");
        }
        function checkWindow() {
            if (NewWin && NewWin.closed) {
                window.clearInterval(intervalID);
                self.count = 0;
            }
        }
        var intervalID = window.setInterval(checkWindow, 500);
    }, function(error) {
        dialogs.error("Error", error.data.error, {
            'size' : 'sm'
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Here is my jsfiddle sample https://jsfiddle.net/ramanKK/hn0fo5oq/

Comment: Check the below answer and see if it is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a variable defined on `$scope` to trigger the value of button instead of using `ng-init`

**HTML**:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <ul ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
        <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="todo in todos">{{todo.text}}
            <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="addLike($index)">value- {{count[$index]}}</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**JS**:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function TodoCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.todos = [{
        text: 'todo one'
    }, {
        text: 'todo two',
        done: false
    }];
    $scope.count = [0, 0];
    $scope.addLike = function(index) {
        var NewWin;
        $scope.count[index] ++;
        if ($scope.count[index] == 1) {
            NewWin = window.open('https://www.google.com');
        } else if ($scope.count >= 2) {
            alert("Back Off Back Off");
        }

        function checkWindow() {
            if (NewWin && NewWin.closed) {
                window.clearInterval(intervalID);
                $scope.count[index] = 0;
                $scope.$apply();
            }
        }
        var intervalID = window.setInterval(checkWindow, 500);
    };
};
```

**JS Fiddle** :https://jsfiddle.net/p41dLjmn/

Comment: Thank You Sir, It worked. How you know that $index will be used?

Comment: There are two items in the todo list. So we need to know for which button the count should be updated.So i am using $index for handling this.

Comment: Yes Sir, I did and how to reload the child window from the parent window
Suppose if 
var NewWin = window.open('http://www.google.com', 'google', 'width=200, height=200, scrollbars=no');
Now from the parent window how i will refresh or reload this NewWin

Comment: What is child and parent window? You should ask this as a new question

Comment: OK i will put it as a new question

Comment: The link for the question i posted:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44926288/how-to-refresh-or-reload-child-window-from-the-parent-window-in-angularjs